# Show that cuts are preserved under homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, functions, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Let $(X, \mathcal{T})$ be a topological space, assume that $X$ has no proper (not $X$ or $\varnothing$) clopen subset.

> Definition: A point $p \in X$ is a cut if $X \setminus\{p\}$ has a
>   proper clopen subset

---

Show that if $(X, \mathcal{T})$ have $n$ cuts, , and $f: (X, \mathcal{T}) \to (Y, \mathcal{J})$ is a homeomorphism then $(Y, \mathcal{J})$ have $n$ cuts

---

**Attempt:**

First show that no proper clopen subset is preserved under homeomorphism. Suppose that $(X, \mathcal{T})$ has no proper clopen subsets, then all proper subsets are either closed or both but not both. Since homeomorphism preserves openness and closedness, therefore there are no proper clopen subsets in $(Y, \mathcal{J})$

Next show that a single cut is preserved. Suppose that $(X, \mathcal{T})$ has $1$ cuts, then there exists some $p$ such that $X \setminus \{p\}$ contains a clopen subset. Let $C \subset X \setminus \{p\}$, where $C$ is clopen. Since $f$ is a homeomorphism, then $f( X \setminus \{p\}) = f(X) \setminus f(\{p\})$ = $Y \setminus f(\{p\})$ and $f(C) \subset Y \setminus f(\{p\})$. Since $f$ preserves clopenness (?), therefore $f(C)$ is a clopen and $Y$ has a single cut.

Similarly, if $X$ has $n$ cuts, then $f( X \setminus \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n p_i) = f(X) \setminus f(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n p_i)$ = $Y \setminus \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n f(\{p_i\})$ and $Y$ has $n$ cuts.

> Can someone verify if this argument is good?

Comment: It is not true that all proper subsets are either closed or open. Think of the rational numbers as a subset of the reals.

Comment: @LeeMosher Ouch you are right...but even then homeomorphism should preserve not open nor closed sets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first part (preserving a cut point) can be made nicer:

Note that "$X$ has a proper clopen subset" is saying the same thing as "$X$ is not connected".

Homeomorphisms preserve connectedness (two ways), so if $h: A \rightarrow B$ is a homeomorphism, then $A$ connected iff $B$ connected (and because of the equivalence) $A$ is not connected iff $B$ is not connected.

If $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a homeomorphism (so has continuous inverse $g: Y \rightarrow X$), and $x \in X$, then $f': X\setminus\{x\} \rightarrow Y \setminus \{f(x)\}$, where $f'$ is the restriction of $f$, is also a homeomorphism , because the restriction of a continuous map is continuous and the same holds for the inverse. And $f'$ and restricted $g$ are still each other's inverses by standard set theory.

The $n$ cuts case is not separate, but follows from the above and $f$ being a bijection. From the first paragraphs it follows, really, that $p$ is a cut in $X$ **iff** $f(p)$ is a cut in $Y$. So both spaces have the same number of them.

Answer (score 2):

Your argument for $1$ cut is probably ok.  Your logic is a little twisted at the beginning.  The lemma should be:

> If $C$ is a proper clopen subset of $X\setminus \{p\}$, then $f[C]$ is
>   a proper clopen subset of $Y\setminus \{f(p)\}$.

For $n$ cuts, you need to prove that each $f(p_i)$ is a cut point of $Y$.  You failed to show this.  Instead you showed that $Y\setminus \bigcup \{f(p_i)\}$ has a proper clopen subset. A circle has a proper clopen subset if you remove two points, yet neither of the points is a cut point! What you need to do here is use your first result to say that each $Y\setminus \{f(p_i)\}$ has a proper clopen subset, and that since $f$ is a bijection the points $f(p_i)$ are discinct, so that you have $n$ cut points.