# Topologically, what distinguishes $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology, cardinals, real-numbers

I thought this question was easy, but turns out to be a little bit tricky

Let us give $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ the usual topology. Then, $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ are:

1. both uncountable
2. both separable, first countable, second countable, suslin
3. metrizable, not compact
4. connected

$$\vdots$$
Seems we require a new concept:

> Let $x \in X$ be a cut point if $X \backslash \{x\}$ has a non-trivial
>   clopen subset.

We know this is a topological invariant. See my answer here: [Show that cuts are preserved under homeomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1826582/show-that-cuts-are-preserved-under-homeomorphism)

It seems that the only distinguishing feature is that $\mathbb{R}$ have different amount of cut points than $\mathbb{R}^2$.

But how many cut points?

Obviously it only takes one to cut $\mathbb{R}$, and it takes uncountable many (like a line) to cut $\mathbb{R}^2$.

And how do we know whether taking away uncountable many points from $\mathbb{R}$ doesn't also produce a clopen subset? In that case, $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ would have same amount of cut points, thus not topologically distinguishable.

Can someone resolve this for me?

Comment: Why not use homology?

Comment: @EduardoLonga Can't use it! Must find simpler concepts to work with.

Comment: One thing that distinguishes the spaces is that you can remove a single point from $\mathbb{R}^2$ and leave it connected. (This can be proven directly, but it's morally rather related to studying the homology)

Comment: Well, then notice that taking a point out of the real line disconnects it, and this does not happen for the plane.

Comment: @EduardoLonga Why use homology? That's a bit of an overkill here.

Comment: It works though...

Comment: @EduardoLonga amigo, can you provide a guide or tutorial how to use homology to distinguish between spaces. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The point is that *every* point of $\mathbb{R}$ is a cut point, while *no* point of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is; together with the fact that if $f:X\cong Y$ is a homeomorphism and $x$ is a cut point of $X$, then $f(x)$ is a cut point of $Y$. With these two facts in hand, it's clear that $\mathbb{R}\not\cong\mathbb{R}^2$: if $f:\mathbb{R}\cong\mathbb{R}^2$, then $0$ is a cut point of $\mathbb{R}$ but $f(0)$ (whatever that is) isn't a cut point of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I don't quite understand your second-to-last paragraph, about removing many points at once; can you elaborate?

Comment: I thought the cardinality of the cut points is a topological invariant. For example, if we take a line out of $\mathbb{R}^2$, then we will have non-trivial clopen subset. The cardinality of the line is uncountable, because there are uncountably many points in the line...

Comment: @BeachedWhale Yes, but that line does not consist of cut points! A cut point is a point that, when you remove it *and only it*, the space becomes disconnected; what you've described is (for want of a better word) a "cut line." The point is roughly that you need to remove more than just one point to make $\mathbb{R}^2$ disconnected; by contrast, you can remove a single point from $\mathbb{R}$ and it will become disconnected.

Comment: Oh...so $\mathbb{R}^2$ has "cut lines" but not cut points

Comment: @BeachedWhale Bingo. It turns out this idea isn't great for distinguishing $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ - cut spaces other than cut points are really complicated to analyze - but yeah, that's the gist.

Answer (score 5):

If you're in the market for more distinguishing features, here's another property that should be preserved under homeomorphism:

In $\mathbb{R}$, a subset $S$ is  connected $\implies S$ is also path connected.  In $\mathbb{R}^2$, however, this is not the case.  See, e.g. the [topologist's sine curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve).

Comment: So then all connected set in $R$ is path-connected, makes sense